# Why are we not allowed to use https for Android XML tools URLs?

Tags: android, xml, https

I just realized by performing a replace all in my strings.xml file today that we are not allowed to put `https` in the xmlns:tools attribute for the Android schema.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces conventionally take the form of URIs because this is a convenient way of ensuring uniqueness. But really, they are just character strings. The "http://" that you find at the start of many namespace names doesn't imply that the HTTP protocol is in use, it's just a conventional way of forming unique names. Because it's just a character string, something looking for "http://www.w3.org/xhtml", say, is not going to recognize "https://www.w3.org/xhtml", because that's a different name and therefore a different namespace.

(Historically, when namespaces were first introduced, some people wanted them to be URIs that actually referred to something on the network; and some organisations including W3C do try to ensure that if you put the namespace URI in the address bar of your browser, you get something meaningful back. But that's a secondary role. Primarily, a namespace name is just a string.)